# Grafana behind an Nginx from a Different Domain returns "Origin not allowed" on Panels

Tags: nginx, grafana, reverse-proxy

Grafana (version 9) is running without proxy on a domainA. I would like to add an Nginx proxy from another domainB.

According to this [post](https://community.grafana.com/t/access-one-grafana-instance-via-two-different-domain/48705/2), Grafana doesn't support multiples domains and need smart proxy.

Based [on official documentation](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/), [this first post](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/45117#issuecomment-1033842787) and [this second post](https://community.grafana.com/t/multiple-root-urls-for-grafana/6562/3), Nginx configuration should looks like

```
# this is required to proxy Grafana Live WebSocket connections.
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

upstream grafana {
  server domainA;
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name domainB;


  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host domainA;
    proxy_pass https://grafana-prj-sso-monitoring.apps.okd.svc.elca.ch;
  }

  # Proxy Grafana Live WebSocket connections.
  location /api/live/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host domainA;
    proxy_pass https://domainA;
  }
}
```

I can reach Grafana through the proxy but panels return "Origin not allowed". I tried to add standard CORS header on both location with no luck

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally this works with a single location

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header Host domainA;
  proxy_set_header Origin https://domainA;
  proxy_pass https://domainA;
}
```

The trick was to change both Host and Origin headers.

Comment: I was not able to use another location than root even with the official recommendation proposing a rewrite. If anyone has an idea, you're more than welcome.

Comment: Thanks it worked. There is probably slight typo in the code. Proper line is `proxy_pass http://domainA;`